# Rspec testing for radio buttons with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, rspec-rails

I have been having problems setting up a test which involves selecting a radio button using Capybara in Rspec. So, I've tried to isolate the problem out as much as possible.

I created a very simple page of 3 radio buttons, that I would like to test by selecting the first button.

However, I keep getting the error

```
Failure/Error: choose('items_1', visible: false)

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find radio button "items_1"
```

The HTML for the page I'm testing is very simple

```
      <body>  
        <h1>Choose</h1>  
          <input type="radio" name="items" id="items_1" value="1" /> first item<br/>  
          <input type="radio" name="items" id="items_2" value="2" /> second item<br/>  
          <input type="radio" name="items" id="items_3" value="3" /> third item<br/>
      </body>
```

My spec is

```
    require 'rails_helper'

    describe 'Radio button testing' do

      it 'selects the first radio button', :feature do
        visit '/choose'
        choose('items_1', visible: false)
        expect(page).to have_content('Choose')
      end

    end
```

I have tried using `choose` since the documentation says it's for radio buttons (both with and without the css id marker)

```
    choose('items_1', visible: false)
    choose('#items_1', visible: false)
```

but neither work.

Maybe something very simple is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you passing `visible: false`?  Capybara can't interact with non-visible elements (just like a user couldn't)

Comment: When I took a `screenshot_and_save` to try and figure out what was going on, the radio buttons did not show up, so I thought is was necessary to set `visible: false` and `visible: false` allows Capybara to interact with hidden elements

Comment: visible: false  allows Capybara to find non-visible elements, not to interact with them. If your radio buttons aren't showing up in a screenshot you need to look at why that's happening, CSS etc...

Comment: I have tried to figure that out, any suggestions? I was using capybara-screenshot gem.  There is not css styling, the setup is as above, very barebones.

Comment: What CSS are you applying to the radio buttons, also what driver are you using?

Comment: No css styling. Capybara and Poltergeist

Comment: https://gist.github.com/twalpole/bfe3bc6c0376e54b4033fd6e9ed8d10b . is a very basic gist with just the HTML you show above and no css that shows `choose('items_1')` works.  I'm guessing visiting '/choose' in your app doesn't produce the HTML you claim it does -- check `page.html`

Comment: Thanks. I've copied your gist into test_choose.rb but am I'm getting `An error occurred while loading./spec/features/test_choose.rb.
Failure/Error: html = DATA.read.` Sorry, but I'm new to a lot of this.

Comment: if you copy the gist into a file, make sure you have the capybara and poltergeist gems installed and then run `ruby test_choose.rb`  it should run - 
  it's not a spec, it's a standalone ruby script.  if I doesn't I have no clue what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, the script runs and I've also changed it to fail, but `page.html` does not launch browser (another configuration?). Using capybara-2.14.0 and poltergeist-1.8.1

Comment: Huh??  What makes think `page.html` would launch a browser?  In your spec `page.html` should return a string which is the current HTML source of the page.  In the gist I posted it would be `sess.html` - Therefore putting the line `puts sess.html` in the gist would output the page source code to the screen

Comment: Got it! Thanks. In my original spec I was checking that the correct page was loaded by `expect(page).to have_content('Choose')`. Now, how to get this work in my spec...

Comment: Buy you were checking for the content 'Choose' AFTER trying to choose a radio button, so it wasn't really checking for the page.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I originally did the check for 'Choose' without any other code in the `it`. The only thing I've been able to figure out is how the radiobutton are created effects whether they show in Capybara, as in here https://gist.github.com/railsnewbie257/254b0a2d61a5f7a4d429305b9913ff6d. So it's still a puzzle to me. The second and third blocks let me `choose`, the first doesn't display and doesn't show  in `puts page.body`

Comment: That would imply that @items is empty so nothing is getting rendered - Tests run in isolation so if you are expecting records to be in the DB for a given test run you have to create them at the beginning of the test/scenario.  Usually in rails that would be done with fixtures or factories.

Comment: OMG, The second I read you comment, I knew that was the problem! What a schoolboy error. Thank you so much for your time and patience, really, really appreciated.